# List of default libraries in Skulpt

Tags: python, libraries, skulpt

I have been trying to find a list of all the libraries that currently work in the latest version of Skulpt. I have tried ones like tkinter and pygame but they don't seem to work. I have checked the Skulpt website and I can't find it there either. Could you post / give me a link to a list of all the libraries that work in Skulpt.

Before you try and close this question because it is too unique to help everyone, it can be useful to all users of Skulpt, to know which libraries work, otherwise they need to find another platform to use.

If you don't know what Skulpt is, it is an in browser python editor that can be embedded with just html and javascript. [Visit it's website here.](http://www.skulpt.org/)

Comment: Looking at the project's README on github (https://github.com/skulpt/skulpt), it looks like Skulpt is currently an incomplete implementation of Python 2.x, without full support for the Python standard library.  This makes it unlikely that it could support many third party packages.  I suspect the best place for this question is the project's mailing list at https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/skulpt.

Comment: Skulpt is not Python. It is an emulation of Python. Its behavior is neither guaranteed nor reliable. It is not suited for serious use.

Comment: OK. I'll post it on there.

Comment: Look in the /src/lib directory. All files larger then +/- 70 bytes are implemented. And then there are bits of matplotlib and numpy are implemented here: https://github.com/waywaaard/skulpt_numpy and https://github.com/waywaaard/skulpt_matplotlib